# array sort by ascendent order in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to make an array sorter in C; but it doesn't works, and I really don't understand why, so i'm asking you help.

```
for(j=0;j<taille;j++){
    for(i=j; i<taille -1;i++ ){

        imin = j;
        nbmin = tableau[j];

        if (tableau[i+1]<nbmin){

            imin = i+1; // on stocke l'indice de la plus petite variable
            nbmin = tableau[i+1]; // on stocke la plus petite variable dans une variable intermédiaire
        }
        tableau[imin] = tableau[j]; // prend la dernière case non triée pour la mettre à l'endroit de la plus petite case du tableau
        tableau[j] = nbmin; // la dernière case non triée contient la plus petite valeur non triée -> la cse est donc triée

    }
}
```

Thank for your help !

Comment: Please use English, not everybody understands French.

Comment: Certain variables are reset when they shouldn't (like imin, nbmin are reset for each j)

Comment: code looks fine, what output are you getting? can you copy here.

Comment: "*it doesn't works*" is the worth trouble report you can give. What is your concept? What do you expect as result? What do you get as result?

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of the outer loop, you want to determine the smallest element of the subarray `[j ... taille]` and copy it to the front. The algorithm you use is straightforward:

- Initialise the minimum to the first element
- Look at the remaining elements to find the minimum
- Swap the first element with the minimum

The inner loop over `i` is the second item on the list, but in your implementation, the initialisation and the swapping occur inside that loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
for(j = 0; j < taille; j++) {
    int imin = j;                           // initialise minimum
    int nbmin = tableau[j];

    for(i = j + 1; i < taille; i++) {       // find minimum
        if (tableau[i] < nbmin) {
            imin = i;
            nbmin = tableau[i];
        }
    }

    tableau[imin] = tableau[j];             // swap elements
    tableau[j] = nbmin;
}
```

(I've also changed the inner index, so that you look at element `tableau[i]` instead of element `tableau[i + 1]`, which I find more natural. And I've made the variables that describe the minimum local to the outer loop.)

Comment: Well, my code is finally working, and I didn't changed it, so, thank for your help, but I'm just more lost than before posting :')

Comment: Well, your code works, but it does too much work. The selection sort that you probably want to do works as describes above. It does at most one swap per outer iteration. Yours effectively uses `tableau[j]` to store the minimum, leaving you with the minimum value in position `j` after each inner iteration. You reset `imin` in each inner iteration, then possible overwrite it and then swap. That's more or less the same as swapping inside the `if` condition. (I say almost, because your code swaps even if the positions are the same.)

Comment: I guess that the variant where the code doesn't work is one where the swap/assignment happens outside the inner loop. In that case the index is very likely wrong, because it is reset in each inner loop. If you want to understand what your algorithm does, create a small array of, say, 4 items, and print it after each iteration. Or, of course, use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use Selection Sort ([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)).

The idea is to find the minimum item in each pass and put it in the proper place.

This is a code snippet to give you the idea. Variable declarations and `swap` routine is skipped.

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    min_index = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (array[j] < array[min_index])
            min_index = j;

    if (min_index != i)
        swap(array[i], array[min_index]);
}
```